# If a user can't read Excel file, can they still view Chart Web Part created from it?

Tags: permissions, excel, excel-services, chart-web-part

Title sums it up. I would just try it myself but my test environment is down and I figured I might get a speedier response here than to wait for that to come up.

If users don't have permissions to read an Excel file uploaded to a document library, can they still view a Chart Web Part that they are given permissions to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing this. When I set item level permissions on the Excel file, excluding the user, then the user will see a white chart web part with a "Chart Errors" link underneath that can be expanded and reads "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".

If the user has limited access to the library, same error.

Only with at least read access to the document/library does the user see the chart web part.